# Remove yellow lilly pollen stain from carpet

Tags: cleaning

My vase of lillies was knocked over and a lot of the pollen went onto my cream coloured carpet.

I have since found that we should have used tape or a vacuum cleaner but my husband went at it with soap and water straight away and it's spread out and now nothing seems to move it.

We now have some very promenant yellow stains in the carpet.

We have tried vanish foam that you rub in and leave dry and vacuum, more soap and water, a carpet cleaner but it's still just as bright.

What can we use to remove it?

Answer (score 1):

Try Isopropyl Alcohol and follow with a mild detergent to remove the alcohol.

This worked for me but I vacuumed first before agitating it with any other implement.

I followed the method in my source. From my research, some methods can make it permanent.
[SOURCE](https://steemersandiego.com/2017/07/06/pollen-and-other-tough-carpet-stains-things-to-do-before-the-carpet-cleaners-take-over/#:%7E:text=Pour%20some%20isopropyl%20alcohol%20onto,stick%20to%20the%20paper%20towel.)